# Get Internet state change while wifi is connected

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-internet

I want to know if there is any intent or broadcast that notifies when internet is connected/disconnected while the wifi/data network is connected all the time. I am aware of CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE but it only notifies when wifi/data is switched on/off.

Thanks

Comment: what you had done please post first.

Comment: I have broadcast receiver with intentFilter action android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE ... but this only is getting called if wifi is switched on/off

Answer (score 0):

In my case this block of code is working fine, you must try it

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
try {
    InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); 
    //You can replace it with your name
        return !ipAddress.equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
}
```

}

Comment: But how can I know where to call this code as I am not getting update..

Comment: Just create a service with broadcast having intent filter of network state change, so whenever network state changes call this method to check whether the internet is connected or not and return a bool according to your code scenario.

Comment: Issue is I only get broadcast if wifi/data is switched ON?OFF.. Not when it is connected and internet is available/unavailable..

Comment: Ok there is another work around, set intent filter as Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK it will be triggered after every minute, so now you can check internet available/unavailable under a method which returns bool and then use that bool according to your scenario.